# Creating asp.net menus with optional check boxes in them

Tags: asp.net, menu, menuitem, checkbox

I want to have an asp.net menu where some menu items have a check box next to them. Some research has indicated that this can be done using menu templates, this approach however will put a check box next to all the menu items; where as in my situation, I would like the check box there for some items and not others.

I am also thinking in my solution that if an item does not have a check box, I would like a gap in the front where the check box should be so that the text in the item is aligned with the text of all the other items that do have check boxes. May I get suggestions as to ways of doing this?

Comment: Do you try OnDataBound event handler? I guess, it can help to choose how to render menu items.